# Reusing a Many-To-Many table

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have the following Model

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DealGroup {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Person> PeopleInGroup { get; set; }
    public Deal Deal { get; set; }
}

public class Deal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeOfDeal { get; set; }
    public DealGroup FromGroup { get; set; }
    public DealGroup ToGroup { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that there are "Deals" made between 2 groups of people (Deal->FromGroup, Deal->ToGroup). In OnModelCreating (I'm using code first) I say:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Deal>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.FromGroup)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.Deal);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Deal>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.ToGroup)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.Deal);
```

And I get an error when I create the DB. I beleive the error is because I'm mapping DealGroup's Deal property twice. When I add 2 properties like:

```
public Deal DealTo { get; set; }
public Deal DealFrom { get; set; }
```

And map each to their own navigation property all is good but this lends for very undesirable code. I would like to have 1 property that goes back to the original Deal object whether your the ToGroup Group or the FromGroup Group.

How can I do this?

Comment: Technically, a `DealGroup` can be both a `FromGroup` in one `Deal` and a `ToGroup` in another `Deal`. You *have* to indicate the role of a group in a deal. If there is one `Deal` property, it can only be either the "to" or the "from" deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reconfigure as such (rename as desired):

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Group {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Person> PeopleInGroup { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Deal> DealsFrom { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Deal> DealsTo { get; set; }
}

public class Deal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeOfDeal { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Group> FromGroups { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Group> ToGroups { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Deal>()
            .HasMany(d => d.FromGroups)
            .WithMany(d => d.DealsFrom)
            .Map(d =>
            {
                d.ToTable("FromGroups");
                d.MapLeftKey("DealId");
                d.MapRightKey("GroupId");
            });

modelBuilder.Entity<Deal>()
            .HasMany(d => d.ToGroups)
            .WithMany(d => d.DealsTo)
            .Map(d =>
            {
                d.ToTable("ToGroups");
                d.MapLeftKey("DealId");
                d.MapRightKey("GroupId");
            });
```

Comment: But what if a Group was very unique to a Deal. A Group isn't used in multiple deals. If thats the Case DealsFrom/DealsTo are not ICollections of Deal they are a single deal and they are both the same deal instance. So is there a way to just have 1 property that goes back to that deal

Comment: No, you should then go with your own proposed alternative (2 navs). Gert is definitely the expert in this area (ef relationships).